# How to infer relationships in source file

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to C#/.NET, just a question on how to infer relationships in source file.
For example, I press F12 in VS to go to definition of class `Exception`:

```
...
public Exception(string message);
...
public virtual string Message { get; }
...
```

So I can guess the in the Exception's constructor, it would be sth like:

```
{
   this.Message = message
}
```

but then I check the source code on https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/exception.cs,f092fb2b893a0162

on line 857, there is a property:

```
internal String _message;
```

so my questions are:

1. why _message is not in VS definition?
2. If a programmer is unable to check the source code file(no internet connection e.g.), how can he know that the Exception's constructor does setup _message inside?

Comment: "*how can he know that the Exception's constructor does setup _message inside*" what exactly do you mean by this.

Comment: I think you are over thinking this, yes sure looking at the source is helpful, though your first point of call should be the doucmentation

Comment: The idea is that you generally should not need to know what the Object does with your parameters internally. The public interface (methods and properties) should be enough for you to use the Object and get the desired result. So it would be helpful if you could give a particular reason why you may need to know the internals of each class you are may use.

Comment: Knowing the internal implementation of third party classes is not necessary most of the time.... I would say it is a very exceptional situation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Because it is in referenced assembly, you cannot show source code for them, you would need to disassemble it first, all you can view is metadata about those classes. It holds for all .NET classes and libraries.
2. You can download tools to disassemble ceratin DLLs, for example you can download dotPeek. [See this google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=.net%20disassebmle&oq=.net%20disassebmle&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4669j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).